# How we create unique id for every replicate in R

Tags: unique

I have a data look like. Kindly anyone help me.
ID  temp
1    25
2    45
3    37
1    32
2    30
3    34

But i want to create unique id for every numeric pattern. My desire output look like

ID  temp New id
1    25   1
2    45   1
3    37   1
1    32   2
2    30   2
3    34   2

I am face this problem. I am try several time but i am fail. Any R experts can help me. Thanks in advance.